# Нужна помощь по структурам и строкам c++

Tags: c++, структуры

?). Есть вот такое задание [image: лаба]

Вот мой код и он не работает в районе `strncpy_s`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct schoolboy
  {
public:
char firstName[30];
char secondName[30];
char addres[50];
int schoolNumber;
int schoolclass;    
 };
 schoolboy recording(schoolboy *base, schoolboy *record, int number);
 schoolboy input(schoolboy *base);
 void recordOut(schoolboy *record);
int main(){
int number;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
cout << "Введите число " << endl;
cin >> number;
schoolboy base[28], record[28];
input(base);
recording(base, record, number);
recordOut(record);
system("pause");
return 0;
}

schoolboy input(schoolboy * base)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cout << "Input First name" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(base[1].firstName, 30);
    cout << "Input Second name" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(base[i].secondName, 30);
    cout << "Input addres" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(base[i].addres, 50);
    cout << "Input Number of school" << endl;
    cin >> base[i].schoolNumber;
    cout << "Input Schoolclass" << endl;
    cin >> base[i].schoolclass;
}
return *base;
}

 schoolboy recording(schoolboy *base, schoolboy *record, int number)
{
if (base->schoolNumber == number)
{
    if (base->schoolclass==10 || base->schoolclass==11)
    {
    cout << "1" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        strncpy_s(record[i].firstName, base[i].firstName, 
sizeof(base[i].firstName));
        strncpy_s(record[i].secondName , 
base[i].secondName,sizeof(base[i].secondName));
        strncpy_s(record[i].addres, base[i].addres,sizeof(base[i].addres));
    }       
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Haven't 10 or 11 class" << endl;
        return *base;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Not found" << endl;
    return *base;
}
return *record;
}
 void recordOut(schoolboy *record)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cout << "i=  " << i << endl;
    cout << record[i].firstName << " " << record[i].secondName << " адрес: " 
<< record[i].addres << endl;
}
}
```

Пробывал и `strcpy`, `strcpy_s`, `strncpy`; Всё не работает, да и `strncpy_s` тоже. В чём проблема и мб есть какие советы по заданию?

Comment: в качестве совета: можно использовать string вместо char[], это значительно упростит задачу и сократит код.

Comment: я вот начал использовать, но возникла новая ошибка
"Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция getline"
`getline(cin, base[i].firstName);`

, где  `base[i].firstName)` - string-элемент массива структуры `base`. В чём проблема?

Comment: всё, исправил, нужно было передавать указатель на элемент

Comment: Если решитесь использовать варианты со strcpy, то перед использованием изучите сигнатуру функции, в Вашем примере просто некорректные аргументы передаются в функцию strncpy_s, поэтому и результат не тот.